# Input a number, output the fixed number from a given sample in Java

Tags: java

I have a list of sample data inputs and outputs numbers as follows:

```
Input Output
84.27  -4
84.31  -3.99
84.35  -3.98
84.39  -3.97
etc...
```

Supposing if an input number 84.33 is entered, the program must output -3.99

Inputs and outputs are sampled data at some point in time, so if any input is given it must give the closest value from the given output based on the closest input value. There's no correlation between inputs and output except it keeps dropping.

Any suggestion or help will be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Could you please explain the logic for outputs?

Comment: Inputs and outputs are sampled data at some point in time, so if any input is given it must give the closest value from the given output based on the closest input value. There's no correlation between inputs and output except it keeps dropping.

Comment: @M.Gomes can you please add that to your question? also please post the code that you've tried so far and what specific issues you are facing.. and are these values in a text file or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NavigableMap** of `Java.util` package will solve your problem, here is the exp code

```
package com.testing;

import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class NavigableMapExp {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        NavigableMap<Float, Float> nm = 
                          new TreeMap<>(); 
        nm.put(84.27f, -4f); 
        nm.put(84.31f, -3.99f); 
        nm.put(84.35f, 3.98f); 
        nm.put(84.39f, -3.97f); 

        System.out.printf("value  : %s%n", nm.floorEntry(84.33f)); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks once again!

Comment: @M.Gomes　A nice solution, but will `floorEntry` give you the closest as requested? According to javadocs *Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key less than or equal to the given key,*  I think your requirements are maybe a bit slack.

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you provide me with your solution? Thanks.

Comment: My solution since deleted was no better.  I suggest that you improve your question.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I didn't down vote your question too. But if you could provide me your solution would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @ankit.vishen *so if any input is given it must give the closest value from the given output based on the closest input value.*  According to your answer `System.out.printf("value  : %s%n", nm.floorEntry(84.34f));` also gives a result of `-3.99` which is **not** closer.